# struggling with JSON parsing in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, nsurlconnection

I am trying to load data in JSON format from my server into IOS application.

Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "BankName": "bank1",
    "CurrencyName": "cur1",
    "SellRate": "0.65",
    "BuyRate": "0.55",
    "OfficialRate": "0.6"
  },
  {
    "BankName": "bank1",
    "CurrencyName": "cur2",
    "SellRate": "1.65",
    "BuyRate": "1.55",
    "OfficialRate": "1.6"
  }
]
```

There are 2 files in my project:

1:

```
import Foundation
class Shot {
    var bankName: String!
    var currencyName: String!
    var sellRate: String!
    var buyRate: String!
    var offRate: String!

    init (data: NSDictionary) {          
        self.bankName = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"BankName")
        self.currencyName = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"CurrencyName")
        self.sellRate = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"SellRate")
        self.buyRate = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"BuyRate")
        self.offRate = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "OfficialRate")
    }

    func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> String {                    
        if let info = data[key] as? String{
            return info
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

2:

```
import Foundation
class JsonTest {    
    func loadJson(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)!) {    
        var urlString = "http://a.com/g.php"        
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let sourceUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)

        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(sourceUrl!){
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
               println(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                var error: NSError?
                var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSArray

                var shots = [Shot]()

                println(jsonData)

                for shot in jsonData{
                    let shot = Shot(data: shot as NSDictionary)
                    shots.append(shot)                    
                }                
                println(shots)   //[jsontest.Shot, jsontest.Shot]                
            }
        }        
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I am trying to populate array automatically when my app starts. To do it I have a code in my mainViewController class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let api = JsonTest()
    api.loadJson(nil)

}
```

The problem occurs when I try to print shots variable in the second file.
it returns `[jsontest.Shot, jsontest.Shot]` when I was expecting the array of dictionaries.

`println(jsonData)` works fine and shows JSON data from URL.

Can anybody advise what is wrong in my program?

Comment: Seems like there are two problems: 1) you're trying to use `println` to debug instead of setting a breakpoint and checking your objects values, and 2) you have not created a `description` or `debugDescription` property for your  object, so `println` on your object is just using some default implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"shots" is an array of instances of Shot, not a dictionary:

```
class Shot {
    var bankName: String!
    var currencyName: String!
    var sellRate: String!
    var buyRate: String!
    var offRate: String!

    init (data: NSDictionary) {
        self.bankName = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"BankName")
        self.currencyName = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"CurrencyName")
        self.sellRate = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"SellRate")
        self.buyRate = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"BuyRate")
        self.offRate = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "OfficialRate")
    }

    func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> String {
        if let info = data[key] as? String{
            return info
        }
        return ""
    }
}

var shots = [Shot]()
let urlString = "http://almazini.lt/getrates.php"
let sourceUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
// Using NSData instead of NSURLSession for experimenting in Playground
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: sourceUrl!)
var error: NSError?
// As I'm using Swift 1.2 I had to change "as" with "as!"
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSArray
for shot in jsonData{
    let shot = Shot(data: shot as! NSDictionary)
    shots.append(shot)
}
println(shots[0].bankName)
```

[image: screenshot]

**Update for Swift 2**

```
var shots = [Shot]()
let urlString = "http://almazini.lt/getrates.php"
// Using NSData instead of NSURLSession for experimenting in Playground
if let sourceUrl = NSURL(string: urlString) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(sourceUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let data = data, jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []), jsonArray = jsonData as? [NSDictionary] {
                for item in jsonArray {
                    let shot = Shot(data: item)
                    shots.append(shot)
                }
                print(shots[0].bankName)
            } else {
                print("no JSON data")
            }
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: can you add to your answer full code text which is used in playground please?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer with the code I used in the Playground.

Comment: thanks! can you tell me what is the best way to create an array of dictionaries with data from JSON. In our example it would be array with two dictionaries inside it. Can we create an empty dictionary and pull data from instance of class Shot? or maybe there is a better way

Comment: For anything more than extracting a few keys here and there, I would use a framework like JSONJoy https://github.com/daltoniam/JSONJoy-Swift or SwiftyJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON . With these frameworks it's more efficient to create objects from JSON and manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two problems:

1. You're trying to use `println` to debug instead of setting a breakpoint and checking your objects values.
2. You have not created a `description` or `debugDescription` property for your  object, so `println` on your object is just using some default implementation.

`shots` is an array of your custom object, so when you call `println`, it's using the `description` for `Array`, which prints out the objects in the array, comma separated, and within square brackets.

The default `description` property for classes in Swift just prints the class name.

Ideally, you should just use a break point to check the values of your object to be certain it initialized correctly, but if it's actually important to get them to print right, it's only a matter of implementing the `description` property:

```
override var description: String {
    get {
        // build and return some string that represents your Shot object
    } 
}
```

Comment: hi, I was using breakpoint ot find out values of my variables. But decided that println will help to understand problem quicker in case somebody will try my code.

Comment: my mistake was that I didn't know that  it is instance of class.  
 can you tell me what is the best way to create variable with an array of dictionaries with data from JSON. In our example it would be array with two dictionaries inside it. Can we create an empty dictionary and pull data from instance of class Shot? or maybe there is a better way ?